# NullPointerException while setting mediaplayer in android studio

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am new to android studio.
 I was trying to make a media player but I receive an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

This is the error which is stopping from loading a media file

I have downloaded the media file from exact that location found in the tutorial.

My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer mplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.k);
    mplayer.start();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide som more information, link to the tutorial maybe? Read [ask] and provide a little more of your code, preferably a [mcve]

Comment: actually i am taking the udemy course by robpercival
and this is almost fullcode bcoz the other lines are just the ones which comes by default when a new project is set up.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `mplayer` variable is null, that is because `R.raw.k` is missing. Are you sure you have a file "r" in the raw resource? Follow this [Media Player tutorial](https://hack4m.com/creating-basic-android-music-player-app-using-mediaplayer/) if you are just beginning with the media player.

Please place your media file in the raw directory and reference it using its correct name.